# using perl how can you figure out how to turn off a specific warning

Tags: perl

I've got some legacy code that I'm dealing with. It's too much to clean up in one shot. It's using \1 inside of the s operator. I looked into perllexwarn and found I can shut it off with 'no warnings qw(syntax)', but I did this with trial and error. Is there an easier way to get right from the warning to the way to shut it off?

It's doing stuff like this:

```
use strict;
$_ = "abc";
s/abc/\1/;
no warnings qw(syntax);
s/abc/\1/;
```

the message it generates is :

```
\1 better written as $1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Execute your script as

```
perl -Mdiagnostics ./a.pl
```

or temporarily add `use diagnostics;` to your script. This will produce something like

```
\1 better written as $1 at ./a.pl line 4 (#1)
    (W syntax) Outside of patterns, backreferences live on as variables.
    The use of backslashes is grandfathered on the right-hand side of a
    substitution, but stylistically it's better to use the variable form
    because other Perl programmers will expect it, and it works better if
    there are more than 9 backreferences.
```

Notice the `(W syntax)`? The letter is one of the following, and the word is the warning class for which you are looking.

- (W) A warning (optional).
- (D) A deprecation (enabled by default).
- (S) A severe warning (enabled by default).
- (F) A fatal error (trappable).
- (P) An internal error you should never see (trappable).
- (X) A very fatal error (nontrappable).
- (A) An alien error message (not generated by Perl).

[diagnostics](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?diagnostics) gets its information from [perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html), which you could search manually instead of using `use diagnostics;`.

---

Other examples:

```
$ perl -Mdiagnostics -we'print undef'
Use of uninitialized value in print at -e line 1 (#1)
    (W uninitialized) An undefined value was used as if it were already
    [...]

$ perl -Mdiagnostics -we'no warnings qw( uninitialized ); print undef'

$ perl -Mdiagnostics -we'sub foo { } sub foo { }'
Subroutine foo redefined at -e line 1 (#1)
    (W redefine) You redefined a subroutine.  To suppress this warning, say
    [...]

$ perl -Mdiagnostics -we'no warnings qw( redefine ); sub foo { } sub foo { }'

$
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd make a global signal handler, set it in a `BEGIN` block so it's compiled in early, and skip *only* the warning you don't want, so you still get any potential unexpected and unrelated warnings (even within the same category, due to not having to disable the whole thing):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

BEGIN {
    $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
        my $warn = shift;
        return if $warn =~ /\\\d better written as/;
        warn $warn;
    };
}

my $x = 'abc';
$x =~ s/(abc)/\1/;

warn "a different warning\n";
```

Output:

```
a different warning
```

Comment: yeah, seems to be the only way to get to early (complile-time) ones using `%SIG`.

Answer (score 2):

You can look the message up in [`perldoc perldiag`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html). This will tell you the warning category it's in.